# Can sources.list only be updated by hand?

Tags: configuration, apt, upgrade

I'm currently running Linux Mint. I remember that under Ubuntu, whenever a new release comes out, it prompts you with a choice of whether to upgrade or not. It seems like this is not happening in Mint, so I decided to do it myself since Lisa came out in December. My /etc/apt/sources.list currently has links to older versions, and there are several of them, some Mint, some Ubuntu, some mediubuntu, etc. Is there a way to update this list automatically? Is there perhaps at least an official sources.list posted somewhere that I can simply get for upgrading to the new Mint version (I'm using `apt-get dist-upgrade`)? Am I missing the point entirely?

Comment: Doing this manually is very little extra work, and preferable to automated alternatives, which are error-prone, offer little benefit to the user, and are a pain to write in a robust fashion. I've never seen an automated method for manipulating text files that was worth the trouble. And they are not common, for the reasons I have mentioned.